# Null space of linear transformation of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The set $\mathcal{P}$of all real polynomials $f(x)$ is a linear subspace of the vector space $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ of real differentiable functions on the real line. Find the null space of the following mappings defined on $\mathcal{P}$.

1. $F_2(f(x)) = xf(x)$
2. $F_3(f(x)) = x^2f''(x)-2xf'(x)$

What's the definition of null space in this context? I've only covered it in the context of matrices.

Note: this is part (c) of the problem set below.

---

[image]

Comment: The null space of what? What's the context?

Comment: @AlexProvost Sorry, I believe I misunderstood the whole problem: the context is http://oi65.tinypic.com/2eqcl8j.jpg part (b) -- I showed that (ii) and (iii) are linear and it proceeds to ask me their null spaces.

Comment: The null space is the set of polynomials that get mapped to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clearly posed, since it omits stating the codomain of the linear maps $F_2,F_3$; since the results are clearly polynomial functions if the argument $f$ is, I'll take those codomains to be $\def\P{\mathcal P}\P$. Also their definition is wrong in that the argument is the function $f$ itself, not its value (at which $x$?) $f(x)$; I would state them as:

- $F_2(f)=(x\mapsto xf(x))$, and
- $F_3(f)=(x\mapsto x^2f''(x)-2xf'(x))$.

So $F_2$ is the function that maps a polynomial function to its product with the identity function $x\mapsto x$, while $F_3$ maps $f$ to a combination of products formed from its first and second derivative. The question about the kernel is in each case to determine for which polynomial functions $f$ the result is the null function.

In the case of $F_2$ we are multiplying the polynomial function $f$ by another fixed polynomial function of degree$~1$. The result is another polynomial function, which is $f$ is nonzero has degree $\deg(f)+1$ (and of course of if $f$ is zero, then so is the result, as $F_2$ is linear). In particular the result will not be zero unless $f$ is, so $\ker(F_2)=\{0\}$, the subspace of $\P$ containing just the zero function. By similar degree consideration you can see that $F_3(f)$ is nonzero whenever $f$ is a nonzero polynomial function of degree other than$~3$, since $x\mapsto xf''(x)-2f'(x)$ can only be nonzero if the two leading terms cancel, which can happen only if $\deg(f')=2$. (The result of $F_3$ is actually that of multiplying that by $x$, in other words applying $F_2$ to the function I wrote, but we have seen that this operation in injective, so $F_3(f)$ is zero only if $x\mapsto xf''(x)-2f'(x)$ is.) To find $\ker(F_3)$ you can limit yourself to polynomial functions of degree $3$. By writing out $F_3(x\mapsto ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$ you can find under which condition on $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$ the result is zero, which I will leave for you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate this.